# GitHub for Windows - Not Getting Any Project Files, Freezes

Tags: github-for-windows

I try to clone a repository from github, and every time, it makes the folder with the project name, it makes the .git folder, and then nothing happens, it just freezes.

Running Windows 7 32-bit

I can download a zip using https, but I want to use git.

I've set up git globals and so on. I suspect it may be an authentication problem, but I have no way of knowing. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: send an email to support@github.com

Comment: Are you connect to internet via proxy server?

Comment: izlesa, yes, I'm now convinced the proxy is the issue. It worked fine when I ran it at home.

Comment: still freezes lot of , unable to do anything and 100% use cpu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Freezes" sounds definitely like a **bug**.

Indeed, keeping the UI responsive was one of the first design goal of GitHub for Windows (*We've mashed up the elegant Caliburn.Micro with ReactiveUI to provide a responsive interface and to allow for greater testability.*)

**Short version:**

send an email to support@github.com

**Long version:**

As stated by the **[GitHub for Windows launch blog post](https://github.com/blog/1127-github-for-windows)**:

> If you find a bug, submit it to support@github.com. Every email is read by a real person

More recently, **xpaulbettsx**, a GitHubber, even **[tweeted about this](https://twitter.com/xpaulbettsx/status/221070164056211456)** :

> Support@ is good for Anything you want to tell GitHub - bugs, features, high 5s; everything but security which go to security@

Comment: Thanks, bug submitted.